# How to pass parameters through a Stateful widget

Tags: flutter, dart

When calling another class I want to initiate that class with a parameter, in the same form as Widgets are often initialized.

When doing this with a `StatefulWidget`, I create a custom Instantiater like I would in C# or other languages I know better than Dart and I pass the parameters to properties of the class.

The Stateful class gives me a blue squiggly line and says I should initiate properties in an "@immutable class" it works but I hate blue squiggly lines.

Is there a better way to pass parameters forward to a stateful class?

```dart
class CreateTest extends StatefulWidget {
  DemandRecord _demandRecord;
  BuildContext _buildContext;
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return CreateTestState(_buildContext,_demandRecord);
  }

  CreateTest() 
  {

  }

  CreateTest.start(BuildContext context, DemandRecord demandRecord) {
    _buildContext = context;
    _demandRecord = demandRecord;
  }  
}
```

I just want to pass it forward...

This is the error ==>

> **This class (or a class which this class inherits from) is marked as '@immutable', but one or more of its instance fields are not final:**

Jamie

Answer (score 3):

This is the correct way to implement what are you trying to do, using a similar structure like that provided in the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CreateTest extends StatefulWidget {
  final DemandRecord demandRecord;
  final BuildContext buildContext;

  CreateTest({Key key, this.demandRecord, this.buildContext}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CreateTestState createState() => _CreateTestState();
}

class _CreateTestState extends State<CreateTest> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return null;
  }

}
```

Then when you want to call it:

```
CreateTest(demandRecord: record, buildContext: context);
```

Comment: Thanks that is very very helpful. Thanks

Comment: One other quick question, I want to pass the variables to the _CreateTestState function what is the purpose of Key do I need to pass it?

Comment: This post will explain https://medium.com/flutter/keys-what-are-they-good-for-13cb51742e7d

Comment: Mazin, thanks I know what a key is for, what I was trying to determine is _why_ specifically had he chosen above to create a key and pass it.

Comment: This doesnt tell the OP how to access the parameters. Looks like the OP figured it out below but within your State class you would access the parameters/variables by using widget.demandRecord, etc...

Answer (score 0):

For those that read this in the future, several months later I found out how to do what I truly wanted to do, but did not know how.

There is a parameter in a  implementation of the controller called # **widget** # that can be used to reach back into the Widget that created the State controller.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CreateTest extends StatefulWidget {
  final DemandRecord demandRecord;
  final BuildContext buildContext;

  CreateTest({Key key, this.demandRecord, this.buildContext}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CreateTestState createState() => _CreateTestState();
}

class _CreateTestState extends State<CreateTest> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
```

// I want to reach back into the class and get the demand record notice the 
// "widget."

```
  Colors localColor = widget.demandRecord.color; 
  if (localColor == Colors.blue) 
     // act on local Color here and notice widget. gave access to
     // parameters passed into StatefulWidget 

    return null;
  }

}
```